# Why "function" keyword is necessary before object name ?All objects are function in real?

Tags: javascript, object

When we make an object like this

```
function myObject(){  
Properties and methods here----
};
```

We write “function” keyword before name of object is it necessary? All objects are functions in real? Can we not write direct object name like this?

```
myObject(){  
Properties and methods here----
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not all objects are functions. (All functions are objects, though.)

Here, `obj` isn't a function:

```
var obj = {
    foo: "bar"
};
```

Nor `dt` here:

```
var dt = new Date();
```

The `function` keyword is necessary in order to say "what follows is a function declaration or function expression." It's just part of the basic syntax of JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

in the first case, the function can be used as the constructor for an object. So you can have:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name
}

Person.prototype = {
    // methods can go in here
}

person1 = new Person("bob");
alert(person1.name) // alerts "bob"
```

It is also true that you can use a function as an object. For example:

```
function myObject() {
    return myObject.test;
}

myObject.test = "bob";
alert(myObject()) // would alert "bob"
```

but all objects are not functions.

```
var someObject = {
     name: "bob",
     moody: "sad"
}

alert(someObject.name); // alerts "bob"
try {
    someObject();
} catch (er) {
    alert(er);  // alerts "TypeError: object is not a function"
}
```

I'd suggest you take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Answer (score 3):

One reason is obviously disambiguity;

```
function foo() 
{
    alert("cake") 
}

foo()
{
    alert("burb");
}

foo();
```

alerts `cake`, `burb`, `cake` as the 2nd `foo() {...}` is just a regular function call followed by a regular compound statement enclosed in `{}`.

Answer (score 2):

`function` declares a function.  Because of the way JavaScript works, a function can be used as a *class*, to make objects.

But if you really just want an object, use squiggly braces, like this:

```
var myObject = {
  x : 30, // a property
  getX : function() { // a method
     return this.x;
  }
}
```

But your understanding of JavaScript needs a lot of work: read a few books about it.

Comment: Not so much class but a constructor. JavaScript doesn't have classes.

Comment: Hi Malvolio,
thx for answer :) and yes i need a lot of work for understanding javascript . i am reading few books and article daily.

Comment: Hi delnan,
so we write the keyword "function" before name of object so we can make a constructor ...ohh thats why we use keyword "new" for making a instance of "objectname"....now i got it ..thx for your support

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript we can create objects in various ways:

1) Literals

```
   let employee = {"name": "tyrion","age":34}
```

2) Constructor functions(functions having this)

```
   function employee(name, age) {
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
   }
```

let specificEmployee = new employee("tyrion",34);

**Constructor function always need to have a new operator to create a object**

3) Using Object constructor

```
   let employee = Object.create(null);
   employee.name = "tyrion";
   employee.age = 34
```

In javascript every thing other than primitive type is an instance inherited from Object constructor.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not required. You can also have:

```
var myObject = {  
   Prop1: "Value1", 
   Prop2: "Value2", 
   Method1: function() {
      alert("hello");
   }
};
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/rKunx/

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
myObject = {
Properties and methods here----
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid the `function` keyword as much as possible in Java you could use classes:

```
class Person {
  name;

  setName(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.doStuff();
  }
  doStuff() {
    //...
  }
}
```

The obvious disadvantage to using classes though is that any property or function has to be accessed with `this`. An advantage of `this` keyword is that it is clear to know that you are referring to a class property or function and not a local one within the function.

Some people use a `var` or `let` in the top:

```
setName(name) {
  let t = this;
  t.name = name;
  t.doStuff();
}
```

Still, many prefer to use a function to define some kind of class instead since that does not need `this` in order to reach the properties which are just variables in the scope of the function. Put inside a module you will still be able to contain these in much the same way you would a class.

If I could make a wish for the future of Javascript it would be to find some way that `this` is implicitly referring to the class in some way to have a smaller code style with less tokens and easier readability.